# enable dd() for drush - temporary://debug_drupal.txt call fails

Tags: drush, debugging

If I included calls to `dd()` from code I run with drush, I see messages like this:

```
WD php: Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://drupal_debug.txt):      [warning]
failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open"
call failed in drupal_debug() (line 1624 of
/home/planetary/April/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module).
```

How to make it so that `dd('...')` actually prints stuff to the drupal_debug.txt file?

Comment: I have not investigated this myself, but it is being tracked in the devel issue queue. Please see http://drupal.org/node/1159158

Comment: Thank you - that is related, but I looked at the patch, it doesn't address the question of how to set the temporary directory, which I think is the only thing needed to answer that question.  I'll try a separate question for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of a [recent change](http://drupal.org/node/1806416) to Drush (March 30, 2013), Drush is aware the  environment variables `TMP` and `TEMP`.  So the solution (on Ubuntu) is:

```
export TMP="/tmp/"
```

and

```
sudo chmod g+w /tmp/drupal_debug.txt
sudo usermod -a -G www-data DrushUser
```